# Parse to DateTime format (M)M/(d)d/yy (h)h:mm tt

Tags: c#, datetime

I thought this would be easy:
I want to parse the following string format to `DateTime`:

"4/25/18 3:11 PM"

and it's a lot more difficult than I expected.

`DateTime.Parse` just returns an exception `Input string not in the correct format`

`DateTime.TryParseExact` is the closest I have come, and it can parse this exact string, but it does not account for when day, month, hour (etc) goes over (or below, depending on the mask) 9 since the mask has to match exactly or it will fail.

```
string input = "4/25/18 3:11 PM";
string input2 = "1/1/18 10:10 AM";
DateTime theDate;
DateTime.TryParseExact(input, "M/dd/yy h:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out theDate);
```

My next idea was to split out the `4`, `25`, `18` and add a 0 if they are < 10, and a 20 concatenated before the 18 but this seems overkill. It also leaves me with the time and making conditions based on if the `tt` is AM or PM.

EDIT: Based on some comments....

I have no control over the input string.

`Convert.ToDateTime("25/4/18 3:11 PM")` throws an exception `{"String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."}`

When I specified the input date as 4/25/18, the input format is clearly M/dd/yy. Unfortunately this can mean the input date can be MM/d/yy etc. We can assume it will always be Month / Day / Year..

TLDR: How can I parse `input` and `input2` to a DateTime cleanly?

Thanks

Comment: What about `TryParse` ?

Comment: `Convert.ToDateTime("4/25/18 3:11 PM")` will return a `DateTime` object from your string. Assuming you're executing from US locale.

Comment: @David ...really?

Comment: `DateTime.ParseExact(s, "M/d/yy h:m tt", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`

Comment: `ParseExact` does take an array of formats, too.

Comment: May be you can fix at source of the datetime string values to return values in uniform format.

Comment: @john https://imgur.com/6Eh9aH3

Comment: @Zemens So is 11/5/2018 the 11th of May 2018, or the 5th of November 2018?

Comment: @DavidZemens That won't work for all cultures, it's awful.

Comment: @Zemens Your code gives me the following exception: `System.FormatException: 'String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.'`

Comment: no, it won't work for all cultures/locales. but if OP doesn't have control over the input *string*, then there's a much bigger problem, no?

Comment: @john If it's for internal, US use, who cares? Not everything is a candidate for internationalization.

Comment: Zemens The input string isn't the problem, the culture running the code is the problem.

Comment: Lots on this has already been written.  Please search.  Keep in mind that date parsing is culture dependent.  `4/1/18` might be April 1st in the US, but it's January 4th in Europe.

Comment: @Phil OP has given no indication that that's the case. For all we know OP is working with a US API but running their code on a machine in Europe. Not everything is a candidate for assumptions.

Comment: He hasn't indicated otherwise either. What's your point? 25/4/2018 is invalid. And as for Zemens' code giving you an error, it works for me.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with OPs code, it will work fine.

Comment: @Phil 25/4/2018 is not invalid. `Convert.ToDateTime("25/4/18 3:11 PM")` works fine for me.

Comment: 25/4/2018 is invalid for US Locale. It's not invalid for most of the rest of the world, however.

Comment: @john You just said that Convert.ToDateTime() didn't work.

Comment: Fortunately there's an overload for that method which accepts a `System.Globalization.CultureInfo` parameter that will handle other locales, I think. I just tested it for French, and it doesn't error .

Comment: @Phil I said that that specific line of code as provided by David, with the date specified exactly as David did, didn't work.

Comment: You have no control over the input string, but you can assume it will always be given in M/D/Y format? Those two statements seem to be at odds...

Comment: @DavidZemens What I mean is that in any digit returned from the input, if it's less than 10 it does not put 0 before it, so I had trouble with the masks. john's answer below seems to be closest to what I need, just testing now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change your code to be like this, and then it should accept both formats with single and double digits:

```
DateTime.TryParseExact(
    input, "M/d/yy h:mm tt",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None,
    out var theDate);
```

The single character `M`, `d`,and `h` components in the format string allow for single or double digits.

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/nauCJI)

Comment: @cdsln I've included a fiddle for you to see it working.

Answer (score 1):

If the code is executed in US Locale *and* the date string is known or expected to be a valid US date format:

```
Convert.ToDateTime("4/25/18 3:11 PM")
```

For other locales (assuming the input string is valid in the current culture) try this overload:

```
Convert.ToDateTime("25/4/18 3:11 PM", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)
```

However, based on your revision and comments if I understand correctly, you expect the date will always be in M/D/Y (US) format:

> I have no control over the input string.
>
> `Convert.ToDateTime("25/4/18 3:11 PM")` throws an exception `{"String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."}`
>
> When I specified the input date as 4/25/18, the input format is clearly M/dd/yy. Unfortunately this can mean the input date can be MM/d/yy etc. We can assume it will always be Month / Day / Year.

Sure. In that case you're attempting to execute against an invalid US date, on a US culture. But if you can assume the date format provided in string will always  be month/day/year, then you should be able to do:

```
 Convert.ToDateTime("4/25/18 3:11 PM", new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US"))
```

This seems to work whether month/day are provided in single or double-digit, and should return valid `DateTime` object based on assumed en-US date string.

Comment: David, I think this answer covers things well :) My main complaint with just throwing code out in the comments was that we only knew the date format in the question, but not the culture running the code (hence the exception I received trying to run the example on a computer in en-GB culture). Thank you for addressing that in your answer here.